# Why is my method going into infinite recursion?

Tags: c++

I've written a method to help build a quadtree. Each quadtree has a root node, and a root node has 4 children. I'm using depth recursion to stop this function from dividing too many times. The depth that is passed in is equal to the log base 2 of the side of the square (a square is always passed in). However, I get infinite recursion from this. Anyone see why?

When I run it, the output is "Depth=0" infinitely many times..

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Are you sure it's recursing infinitely and not just exhausting your stack?

Comment: What exactly is the value of `depth`? Even a relatively small value can cause an exponential number (`4^depth`) of recursive calls.

Comment: In buildTreeHelper method in QuadTree could you substitute "QuadtreeNode * &n" for "QuadtreeNode *n" for the second argument and check for result ??

Comment: How can we make sense of this question without the code?

Comment: infinite recursion -> all hell breaks loose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `n->isLeaf()` condition means "all `n`'s children are null", then I suppose it is always false here.

Comment: Yes that is what it means. Why so?

Comment: Because you allocate the children few lines upper. :)

Comment: But eventually itll stop, and when it stops, the last nodes will end up being leaf nodes

Comment: There will be leaf nodes, but you won't initialize their `n->element`, because the `buildTreeHelper` called for them would immediately `return` by the `depth<=0` condition. I think you should do it as follows:

    if(depth<=0){
        n->element=*img(x,y);
        return;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any issue with the depth check. Are you sure you pass the right depth to the first call? Maybe it isn't infinite, just tooooo deep?

Comment: Lol well I put a cout line if depth==0, so that it outputs depth. It just outputs depth=0 infinitely.

Comment: Infinitely, or just 4^n times (where n is the original depth)?

Comment: Have you tried it with small values for depth, e.g `depth=1` or `depth=2` ?

Comment: Now I did. I get a seg fault error. Something with my copy constructor. Let me post that. Its a little funky lookin

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but display depth at the first call.
If its value is NaN. you got your answer.

Comment: NaN? In an `int`? That _would_ be impressive :-)

Comment: based on your edit I don't think this is the solution. But if depth value is Nan (Not a number), then (depth<=0) is always false. And ok ... I realised anyway I am saying crap since depth is an int.

Comment: At the same time NaN is not forbidden for an int. It is just never implemented :p

Answer (score 0):

Your handling on the recursive call to `buildTreeHelper` seems perfectly correct. You check the `depth` terminating condition before recursing, and you always call it with `depth-1`.

The only *potential* prolem I can see is if it's the constructor calls (the ones creating the children) which call `buildTreeHelper` again. That could result in infinite recursion if, for example, the constructor always calls `buildTreeHelper` with a object variable for `depth` (it would have the same or a greater value each time).

Comment: Actually I just realized my copy constructor for nodes is a little funky. Lemme post it and see if its ok

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace "QuadtreeNode * &n" with "QuadtreeNode *n" for second argument in buildTreeHelper(...) and check for result please ???

Comment: even if depth = 1 or 2 ?? you mean segmentation fault right ??

Answer (score 0):

Where is the original call to `buildTreeHelper`?  I can just imagine its in the constructor.