# Recursive copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm attempting to write a copy constructor that takes a node of a quad tree, and copies that node, along with all its children, and its children, and so on. Here's what I have:

```
 Node(const Node & n) {

    nChild=new Node(*(n.nwChild));
    neChild=new Node(*(n.nChild));
    eChild=new Node(*(n.seChild));
    wChild=new Node(*(n.sChild));   
}
```

I feel like the last 4 lines are a little funky. Does what I'm doing make sense?

Comment: That code will blow up if one of the `n.??Child` is `NULL` methinks.

Comment: But doesnt it check against that?

Comment: your copy constructor will only return prematurely if *all* of the `??Child` members are `NULL`, if you want to return if any one of them is `NULL` you need to use the `||` operator.

Comment: -1 You asked a question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332811/why-is-my-method-going-into-infinite-recursion . You could (and should) have added the sample code there, instead of posting it here, as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor isn't exception-safe - suppose the second `new` throws `bad_alloc`, then how is the first one going to be cleaned up?

You could probably make your own life easier by changing the `Child` fields to your favourite smart pointer. If you don't have a favourite smart pointer, introduce yourself to some ;-)

[Edit: just noticed that you didn't provide the data member definitions, I just assumed they were raw pointers. Apologies if they're already smart pointers.]

The early-out looks a bit weird - how come if all four children on the rhs are NULL, then the x/y/height/width aren't copied? Normally those members would be handled by an initialization list. And should you do something special if *any* of the children is NULL, rather than *all* of them? Currently you don't handle nodes with children in one direction but not all 4. If it's a property of your tree that every node has either 4 children or none, then you don't need to check all 4, but you *do* need to initialize the various fields when you copy a leaf node. If it's possible for a node to have exactly 1 child, then you don't copy that node correctly.

Other than that, the basic logic seems OK to me, in the sense that provided nothing goes wrong, it will recursively copy.

Answer (score 2):

Makes sense to me. This is a recursive deep copy, should work fine. But don't forget to free all this memory in the destructor. And beware of temporary copies of `Quadtree` when coding, they may be brutal if the tree is large.

The only real issue with this code is that it's miles away from being exception safe. For one, it should be written using an [initializer list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6), this way:

```
Quadtree::QuadtreeNode::QuadtreeNode(const QuadtreeNode & n) 
 : x(n.x), y(n.y), height(n.height), width(n.width),
   nwChild(new QuadtreeNode(*(n.nwChild)), // ...
```

The constructor body can remain empty unless you want to do more than initialize the members. After doing this, you might want to consider swapping bare pointers for some kind of smart pointer. This will be a good foundation towards making the class exception-safe.

Comment: I'm getting a whole lot of "use of unitilized values" and "invalid read size" by the the last 4 lines and a " Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" for the first line. What can this mean?

Comment: You might want to do it in a friend factory function to maintain a set of the already copied nodes and prevent cycles that would cause a stack overflow.

Comment: But don't forget the rule of three. You'll need a useful destructor and a deep-copy assignment operator (possibly using copy-and-swap) to go along with your copy constructor.

Comment: @bitmoe the valgrind warnings mean that the `n` that you passed in wasn't properly initialized. Is it possible that your default constructor doesn't set `nwChild`, etc, correctly?

Comment: My default constructor just sets each child=NULL. So there are 4 such lines in the constructor. Is this ok?

Comment: @bitmoe: Sounds OK. But don't do it inside the constructor body; use an initializer list.

Comment: @bitmoe: so you default-construct one object, its children are set to null. Then you copy it. The copy's children *aren't* set to null, because the copy constructor doesn't set them. So possibly the error is coming when you copy a copy.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the good answers here (I upvoted Jon's), I'd like to introduce a cool new way to gain the exception safety in C++0x.  Your compiler probably doesn't implement it yet.  But I have high hopes a year from now that will not be the case.

I'm starting with Jon's copy constructor:

```
Quadtree::QuadtreeNode::QuadtreeNode(const QuadtreeNode & n) 
 : x(n.x), y(n.y), height(n.height), width(n.width),
   nwChild(new QuadtreeNode(*(n.nwChild)), // ...
```

And now assume you have a default constructor as you described in one of your comments:

```
Quadtree::QuadtreeNode::QuadtreeNode() 
 : x(0), y(0), height(0), width(0),
   nwChild(nullptr), // ...
```

Now you can transform Jon's copy constructor into an exception safe one by calling the default constructor first! :-)  And it ironically comes out looking much like your original code:

```
Quadtree::QuadtreeNode::QuadtreeNode(const QuadtreeNode & n)
     : QuadtreeNode()
{
    if(!(n.nwChild==NULL && n.neChild==NULL && n.seChild==NULL && n.swChild==NULL))
    {
        x=n.x;
        y=n.y;
        height=n.height;
        width=n.width;
        nwChild=new QuadtreeNode(*(n.nwChild));
        neChild=new QuadtreeNode(*(n.neChild));
        seChild=new QuadtreeNode(*(n.seChild));
        swChild=new QuadtreeNode(*(n.swChild)); 
    }
}
```

Explanation:  This is called *delegating constructors*.  And is a new feature of C++0x.  You can literally call one constructor from another.  And when any constructor completes, the object is considered constructed.  From that point on, any exception that gets thrown, will activate the destructor to clean up.  So the default constructor is often a convenient way to construct the object in a *noexcept* manner.  Then you can build up your object in a natural way knowing that the destructor will be called if an exception is thrown.

Comment: And what happens if the new QuadtreeNode to initialized swChild terminates with an exception?  Unless you're into try/catch blocks, each pointer must be in a separate class type object, so that all of those successfully created will automatically be cleaned up in case of failure

Comment: I fear you've missed the point of my post:  New feature; delegating constructors; easy exception safety.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf , 15.3 [except.handle], paragraph 11.

Comment: Yes and no.  The delegating constructor does allow the QuadtreeNode destructor to handle the cleanup, since once any constructor has finished, the object is considered constructed, and its destructor will be called.  But in this case, I still think using a separate class to wrap each pointer (e.g. copy_ptr) is a cleaner solution.  And it works with current compilers:-).

Answer (score 1):

How are the nodes assigned? I see a problem where if this case

```
 1   3
   5 
 7   9
```

if I am trying to copy `5`, and `1` has a `se` pointer to `5`, it would remake `5`, which in turn remakes `1` and so on.

Comment: If that's the case then it's not a quad *tree*, it's a graph with at most 4 edges at any one vertex.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm having some difficulty understanding the reponses,
because they refer to a conditional test which I don't see in
your original code.  However...

IIUC, you want to do a deep copy.  There are two issues which
have to be considered: what to do if one (or more) of the
pointers is null, and how to make the code exception safe.  The
most obvious solution to both of these is to use a smart pointer
for each of the pointers, which does the deep copy and makes all
the necessary checks.  Designing a good generic copy_ptr isn't
trivial, since it should handle polymorphic pointers as well.
But for any one case, or given convention, it's pretty simple;
if Node isn't polymorphic, then the copy ctor for shared_ptr can
be as simple as:

```
copy_ptr( T const& other )
    : m_ptr( other.m_ptr == NULL ? NULL : new T( *other.m_ptr ) )
{
}
~copy_ptr()
{
    delete m_ptr;
}
```

(Use the swap idiom for asignment, and provide the other usual
smart pointer functions.)

Do this, and you can put the initializers directly in the
initialization list:

```
Node( Node const& other )
    : nChild( other.nChild )
    , neChild( other.neChild )
    //  ...
```

(Without the smart pointers, or at least a separate class type
encapsulating each pointer, you'll have to initialize the
pointers to null in the initialization list, then assign the
newed pointers to them in a try-catch block in order to delete
the already newed objects in case of an exception.)